# mat-tab-group sub components not showing up

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have 3 mat-tab labels, and I embedded my own component data like this:

```
<mat-tab label="Label 1"><my-component></my-component></mat-tab>
```

But my-component isn't showing up. What could be the reason?

Comment: Are the tabs showing up ?

Comment: Yes, the tabs are showing up.

Comment: Are you sure the selector name my-component is correct? Or is it app-my-component?

Comment: Yep, that's done it. It was app-my-component. Thank you so much.

Comment: Happy to help! :)